# Ошибка TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'str'

Tags: python

`send_telegram = '\t\n'.join((title + '\n', 'Автор: ' + field[34].text + '\n', description[1].text + '\n') + tuple(download_links))`

ошибку выдает эта строчка, подскажите что ему не нравится?

```
html = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
title = html.find('h1', class_='title')
field = html.find('div', id='main').find_all('a')
description = html.find('div', id='main').find_all('p')
```

вот так задаю переменные

Answer (score 0):

`join` может соединять только строки

проверьте, а везде ли у вас строки в передаваемых параметрах, например `field[34]` вообще существует так же как и `description[1]`?

и если существуют, то какой текст выдают